# How to add an activity-indicator on a page level?

Tags: nativescript

I would like to add an activity-indicator widget in my login page but I would like it to cover the whole screen, so I can prevent double click on the Login button.

Any idea, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wrap everything in a GridLayout, add a StackLayout as the last item in the row you want to cover. The StackLayout by default will cover the whole screen. Then you can show/hide via data. For example:

```
<GridLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        // All your page content goes here! 
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="dimmer" visibility="{{showLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'}}"/>
    <GridLayout rows="*" visibility="{{showLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'}}">
        <ActivityIndicator busy="true" />
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

I have a "dimmer" StackLayout that I animate to be semi transparent black, then the Activity Indicator sits on top.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the code... it's working like a charm!

Comment: I think the xml markup in the answer is wrong (see line 5)...could you fix it for future reference? Thanks :)

Comment: I suppose the closing tag `</StackPanel>` should be used instead of self closing tag.
btw this solution does not work for me. TextFields and Buttons are still clickable under the dimmer `StackPanel`

Comment: To make TextFields and Buttons not clickable and to hide the TextField cursor, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42331788/882912

Comment: adding ```(tap)="doNothing()"``` into stacklayout.dimmer safe me from this problem

Comment: Self-closing StackLayout and ActivityIndicator elements are not supported in newer versions. Just change them to explicitly closed versions (e.g. `<ActivityIndicator busy="true"></ActivityIndicator>` instead of `<ActivityIndicator busy="true" />`)  and it will work fine.

Comment: is dimmer a built in class?

Comment: worked for me !!! but insted of closing like "/>" user proper closing tag

Comment: But it has to be the last item. I had it as the first item and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

not sure what layout you have i will only put example(somehow simplified) from my project

Inside page u can put something like this, both StackLayout and ActivityIndicator are inside GridLayout which takes whole size of page

> ```
>   <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
>
>       <StackLayout  visibility="{{ showLogin ? 'visible' : 'collapse'}}" row="0" column="0">
>           <!--Login form, as you have defined-->
>       </StackLayout>
>        
>        <!--Indicator on whole page, colSpan and rowSpan force ActivityIndicator to takes whole page-->
>       <ActivityIndicator visibility="{{ !showLogin ? 'visible' : 'collapse'}}" busy="{{ !showLogin }}" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"  row="0" column="0" />
>
>   </GridLayout>
> ```

And inside javascript code

> ```
> /*somehow add showLogin property to bindingContext*/
> page.bindingContext.set("showLogin",false) //false for show ActivityIndicator
>
> /*or*/
> page.bindingContext.set("showLogin",true) //true for show form
> ```

But best would be to put to already defined Observable which you should have assigned to bindingContext

So based on showLogin property u will get visible either ActivityIndicator(on whole page) or form

Not sure if i forgot something but if something, write comment :)

Answer (score 1):

The activity indicator on its own won’t prevent dual submissions of your forms. In addition to displaying an ActivityIndicator, you should also set the `isEnabled` flag on your Button UI components to `false` during the submission. For example:

```
<!-- template -->
<Button [isEnabled]="!isAuthenticating" (tap)="submit()"></Button>

// JavaScript/TypeScript
export class LoginComponent {
  isAuthenticating = false;

  submit() {
    this.isAuthenticating = true;
    doTheActualLogin()
      .then(() => {
        this.isAuthenticating = false;
      });
  }
}
```

You can find a complete implementation of a login that prevents dual submissions and uses an ActivityIndicator in the [NativeScript Groceries sample](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/). Take a look at how the `isAuthenticating` flag is used in [this `login` folder](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/tree/9eb6fea66e3912878815b86aa5ce7b812e22eac5/app/login) for the specific implementation.