# NativeScript: Disable all controls while ActivityIndicator is shown

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Lets say there is a login page with username\password TextFields and login Button. When the button is pressed a request is set to a server and ActivityIndicator is shown.
Currently I put StackLayout on top of all other controls not to give the user a possibility to click on them while processing the request. But in some cases TextField stays focused and the user can type there.

I'm already using a component to wrap all TextFields to show validation errors:

```
@Component({
  selector: "field",
  template: "<grid-layout><ng-content></ng-content>...</grid-layout>"
})
export class FieldComponent {
  @ContentChild(NgModel) private input: NgModel;
  ...
}
```

My question is can I set isEnabled property to false on TextField inside `ng-content` from `FieldComponent` having `NgModel` or in some another way?
If it is impossible what is the best practices in this case to disable inputs when an app is busy?

Comment: Depending on your design requirements, you should be able to use the nativescript-loading-indicator plugin to show a modal indicator.  When the modal is shown, you will be unable to interact with elements on the screen.

https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-loading-indicator

Comment: thanks, I'll check it. But look like it just adds an additional layer and I'm not sure that it disables input if an element is already focused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple way you can do this;

1. You can use a `ngIf` or binding on `isEnabled` to disable it based on a data bound value.
2. You can create a simple routine that you call (my preferred method).

```
require("nativescript-dom"); 
function screenEnabled(isEnabled) {
       runAgainstTagNames('TextEdit', function(e) { e.isEnabled = isEnabled; });
       runAgainstTagNames('Button', function(e) { e.isEnabled = isEnabled; }); 
}
```

The `nativescript-dom` plugin has the runAgainst*, or getElementBy* wrappers to talk to the native layer like you were talking to a html dom.

Full disclosure, I'm the author of `nativescript-dom`, it is one of the plugins that I use in almost every app/demo I do.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution for NativeScript+Angular:

1. setControlInteractionState() is recursive.
2. the TextField cursor is hidden (using native android API).

**XML:**

```
<GridLayout #mainGrid rows="*" columns="*">  
  <!-- Main page content here... -->
  <GridLayout *ngIf="isBusy" rows="*" columns="*">
     <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*" style="background-color: black; opacity: 0.35">
     </GridLayout>
     <ActivityIndicator width="60" height="60" busy="true">
     </ActivityIndicator>
  </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

or

```
<GridLayout #mainGrid rows="*" columns="*">  
  <!-- Main page content here... -->      
</GridLayout>
<GridLayout *ngIf="isBusy" rows="*" columns="*">
   <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*" style="background-color: black; opacity: 0.35">
   </GridLayout>
   <ActivityIndicator width="60" height="60" busy="true">
   </ActivityIndicator>
</GridLayout>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { View } from "ui/core/view";
import { LayoutBase } from "ui/layouts/layout-base";
import { isAndroid, isIOS } from "platform";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "./SignIn.html"
})
export class SignInComponent {

    @ViewChild("mainGrid")
    MainGrid: ElementRef;

    isBusy: boolean = false;

    submit() : void {
        try {
            this.isBusy = true;
            setControlInteractionState(<View>this.MainGrid.nativeElement, false);
            //sign-in here...
        }
        finally {
            this.isBusy = false;
            setControlInteractionState(<View>this.MainGrid.nativeElement, true);
        }
    }

    setControlInteractionState(view: View, isEnabled: boolean) : void {
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = isEnabled;
        if (isAndroid) {
            if (view.android instanceof android.widget.EditText) {
                let control = <android.widget.EditText>view.android;
                control.setCursorVisible(isEnabled);
            }
        }
        if (view instanceof LayoutBase) {
            let layoutBase = <LayoutBase>view;
            for (let i = 0, length = layoutBase.getChildrenCount(); i < length; i++) {
                let child = layoutBase.getChildAt(i);
                setControlInteractionState(child, isEnabled);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

NS 2.5.0

Comment: This works beautifully. It would be ideal if the grid that contains the ActivityIndicator could exactly overlay the #mainGrid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found an easiest solution in Angular, so i am posting here for any future reference. First in `app.component.html` file i added a Grid and `ScrollView` like following:

```
 <GridLayout>
    <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
    <!-- hack to block UI -->
    <ScrollView isUserInteractionEnabled="false" *ngIf="isLoading">
        <ActivityIndicator busy="true"></ActivityIndicator>     
    </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

Notice the `page-router-outlet` which is inside the Grid. By default it will be place at row="0". The next thing is `ScrollView` which has isUserInteractionEnabled set to false. 
Now in your `app.component.ts` file add a a variable called `isLoading` and toggle it using some kind of events e.g RxJs Observable events

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @KTCO's answer to get the size of the overlay exactly the same as the main grid:

```
import { Size, View } from "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view";
import { GridLayout } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/grid-layout/grid-layout";
...
...
dialogSize: Size;
mainGrid: GridLayout;
...
submit() {
  this.mainGrid = <GridLayout>this.MainGrid.nativeElement;
  this.dialogSize = this.mainGrid.getActualSize();
  .....
  .....

<GridLayout *ngIf="isBusy" rows="auto" columns="auto">
  <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*" [width]="dialogSize.width" [height]="dialogSize.height" style="background-color: black; opacity: 0.35">
  </GridLayout>
  <ActivityIndicator width="50" height="50" busy="true">
  </ActivityIndicator>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but sometimes I just got to do things my way. If you want to accomplish this programmatically:

```
const excludedView = someViewToBeExcluded;

const enabler = (parentView:View, enable:boolean) => {
  parentView.eachChildView(childView => {
    if (childView != excludedView) {
      enabler(childView, enable);
      childView.isEnabled = enable;
    }          
    return true;
  });
};

enabler(page, false);
```

Note: This will not disable/enable the initial `parentView` (ie. the `page` in this example)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some more information. Every `View` has a [isEnabled](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/4f12fee2ef2258926be4507f1cd63aa4872c6bba/packages/core/ui/core/view/index.d.ts#L458) and [isUserInteractionEnabled](https://docs.nativescript.org/api/#isuserinteractionenabledproperty) properties.

- **isEnabled**: Gets or sets a value indicating whether the view is enabled. This affects the **appearance** of the view.
- **isUserInteractionEnabled**: Gets or sets a value indicating whether the user can interact with the view. This does **not** affect the appearance of the view.

In Angular, I do something like:

```html
<Button
  text="Tap Me!"
  (tap)="onBtnTapped($event)"
  [isEnabled]="isEnabled$ |async"
  [isUserInteractionEnabled]="isEnabled$ |async"
></Button>
```

Then in the component you can enable/disable like:

```js
isEnabled$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

this.isEnabled$.next(true); // Enable
this.isEnabled$.next(false); // Disable
```

I have also set `isEnabled` on a `GridLayout` or `StackLayout` to gray out a bunch a bunch of child views at the same time. From what I've seen it doesn't appear `isUserInteractionEnabled` will affect child views like `isEnabled` does so that one might need to be set on each view individually, but I could be wrong.